# What does the "Under siege" debuff do to cities?

Tags: civilization-6

I sometimes see it but the game fails to mention what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cities under siege will not regenerate their health each turn, making them easier to capture.

To siege a city, every tile immediately adjacent to the city needs to be under the attacking players zone of control.

Comment: Ranged units don't exert ZoC (without the promotion), but their tile counts.  Melee units exert ZoC within one tile, but not across rivers.

Comment: @mmatthews: So in other words, all city-adjacent tiles need to either **contain** a unit, or be **adjacent to** a unit that has ZoC in order for a siege to take place?

Comment: @Flater That is my understanding.  I haven't played in R&F, I'm not sure if anything changed with the expansion.